# Mathematically show that MC cross AC can only occur on upward sloping part of MC curve

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, cost

Question as in title, does anyone know how to show it? with mean value theorem?

I can prove that AC is minimised at MC=AC but I'm not sure how to show MC can only cross AC at upward-sloping point of MC

My first part simply takes AC = c(q)/q and AC' eventually after simplifying leads to c'(q) = c(q)/q [given AC=0 at min point]
so thus c'(q) = MC and therefore at the min point AC = MC

I am thinking how to show using mean value theorem that AC & MC can only cross at the upward sloping MC curve (where MC' >0); I know graphically how and why but not how to start off to show?

[image: Second-order of AC'']

Comment: When you proved AC is minimised at MC=AC, did you look at the second order conditions? If yes, can you please [edit](https://economics.stackexchange.com/posts/47374/edit) your work into your question?

Comment: You need to make some assumptions on your cost function for this to be true

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker yes; the assumptions are total cost function is increasing and smooth (first and second derivatives are continuous) with , and MC function is first strictly decreasing and then strictly increasing in q

Comment: @Giskard added the AC'',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the assumption that $C(q)$ is continuously differentiable we have for all $q$:
$$
qAC(q) = C( q ) = FC + \int_0^{q} MC(x) \text{d}x. 
$$
Taking the difference for any pair $q,\hat{q}$:
$$
qAC(q) - \hat{q}AC(\hat{q}) = \int_{\hat{q}}^{q} MC(x) \text{d}x. \tag{1}
$$
The left hand side may be reformulated:
$$
q\left(AC(q) - AC(\hat{q}) \right) + \left(q - \hat{q}\right)AC(\hat{q}) = \int_{\hat{q}}^{q} MC(x) \text{d}x 
$$
and the form we will use is
$$
q\left(AC(q) - AC(\hat{q}) \right) = -\left(q - \hat{q}\right)AC(\hat{q}) + \int_{\hat{q}}^{q} MC(x) \text{d}x \tag{2}
$$
Assume $C(q)$ is strictly convex and $MC'(q)$ switches sign somewhere; furthermore assume that $q_c$ exists where $AC(q_c) = MC(q_c)$, and $AC(q)$ is minimized at this point.

---

**We will first show that $q_c$ is not in the range where $MC(q)$ is decreasing.**

**Proof by contradiction:**

 Assume $MC(q)$ is strictly decreasing at $q_c$, thus there exists a small environment $(q_c, q_c + \epsilon)$ such that for $q \in (q_c, q_c + \epsilon)$ we have
$$
\int_{q_c}^{q} MC(x) \text{d}x < \left(q - q_c\right)MC(q_c).
$$
Combining this with (2), we get
$$
q\left(AC(q) - AC(q_c) \right) < -\left(q - q_c\right)AC(q_c) + \left(q - q_c\right)MC(q_c) = 0.
$$
From this it follows that
$$AC(q) < AC(q_c),$$
contradicting the assumption that $q_c$ minimizes $AC(q)$.

---

**We will now show that there is no $q_b > q_c$ for which $AC(q_b) = MC(q_b)$.**

**Proof:**

 At $q_b$  $MC(q)$ is strictly increasing, thus
$$
\int_{q_c}^{q_b} MC(x) \text{d}x < \left(q_b - q_c\right)MC(q_b).
$$
As $AC(q)$ is minimized at $q_c$, we also have $-AC(q_c) > -AC(q_b)$, and thus
$$
q_bAC(q_b) - q_cAC(q_c) > q_bAC(q_b) - q_cAC(q_b) = \left(q_b - q_c\right)AC(q_b) 
$$
Combining these inequalities with
$$
qAC(q) - \hat{q}AC(\hat{q}) = \int_{\hat{q}}^{q} MC(x) \text{d}x. \tag{1}
$$
we get
$$
\left(q_b - q_c\right)AC(q_b) < q_bAC(q_b) - q_cAC(q_c) = \int_{q_c}^{q_b} MC(x) \text{d}x < \left(q_b - q_c\right)MC(q_b),
$$
thus $AC(q_b) < MC(q_b)$.

Comment: I feel that this proof could be simplified and made more elegant, but I have spent too much time on it as it is.

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed proof! that was exactly what helped me to understand!

Answer (score 2):

You claim that

> AC is minimised at MC=AC

thus at this quantity $q_c$ we have $AC'(q_c) = 0$.

We will show that given the assumptions $MC'(q_c) \geq 0$, that is $MC$ cannot be decreasing in $q$ at this location.

For all $q$ it is true that
$$
AC'(q) = \frac{MC(q)-AC(q)}{q}.
$$
For all $q > q_c$ we have
$$
0 = AC'(q_c) = \frac{MC(q_c) - AC(q_c)}{q_c} = \frac{MC(q_c) - AC(q_c)}{q}  
$$
(as the numerator is $0$),
and if $MC$ is decreasing at $q_c$, then for all $q$ close enough to $q_c$ we have
$MC(q_c) > MC(q)$. Combine this with the above and we get
$$
0 = \frac{MC(q_c) - AC(q_c)}{q} > \frac{MC(q) - AC(q)}{q} = AC'(q), 
$$
where $-AC(q_c)>-AC(q)$ holds because $q_c$ is supposed to be where $AC$ is minimized.

We have shown that for all $q > q_c$ the inequality $0 > AC'(q)$, which (together with the assumption that second derivatives are continuous) contradicts $AC'(q_c) = 0$.